# OS X Mavericks: How to synchronously invoke Finder's 'Tags...' editor from a script

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, osx-mavericks, finder

I am developing an automator action that gets invoked by a hotkey from Finder. In this action the user shall (interactively) edit the tags of the Finder selection (screenshot), which is then post-processed by my action:

```
on FILES=<Finder selection>
open 'Tags...' overlay window
wait until 'Tags...' overlay window is closed
process FILES (by shell script, apple script, whatever)
```

[image]

While I can trick (more or less successful) Finder by UI scripting or other hacks into showing the 'Tags...' overlay, I have no clue how to wait until it is finished. (Waiting for a file change is not an option, as the user may also cancel the tag editing.)

Or maybe there is any other file tag editor available I could use for the purpose? For OpenMeta tags I would use [Tagger](http://hasseg.org/tagger/), but AFAIK this does not support Mavericks tags.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the most recent version of the free [TagIt utility](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/tagit/) from Ironic Software (the OpenMeta maintainers) writes *both*, OpenMeta and Mavericks tags. One can invoke it synchronously from a script with `open -W -a TagIt <file1> <file2> <...>`.

Nevertheless, I would prefer the Finder 'Tags...' editor.